# Serverside SSH security best practices

Tags: ssh

In light of the 2006 Debian OpenSSL fiasco, it seems prudent to take additional precautions as part of a "defense in depth" strategy against future possible vendorside-introduced ssh security vulnerabilities. What are some measures that can mitigate against bugs similar to the 2006 Debian OpenSSL bug in future? Some ideas:

- Use a different port number than port 22 (but there aren't that many port numbers)
- Port knocking (isn't this just security theatre?)
- Using long, randomly generated usernames in AllowedUsers (does this really help?)
- IP whitelisting using iptables
- Require both password and public key, using AuthenticationMethods "publickey,password" "publickey,keyboard-interactive"
- Require two-factor authentication using Google Authenticator.

Would these measures be of significant benefit or are they just "security theatre"?
Are there any other measures that I'm missing?

Comment: You seem to be listing measures / mitigations that are restricted to configuration changes on the server itself. Most "defense in depth"  infrastructure designs would rely on more external security controls, such as firewalls, network segmentation and ACL's ,  VPN servers, etc. to restrict and control the ssh/management access to servers. - But if you can't access the ssh daemon (or any other network service due to firewall restrictions) you can't exploit any vulnerabilities in the product either.

Comment: When you can access the SSH daemon, like any other service, it really depends on the nature of a vulnerability if "better" , more security conscious configuration settings will increase your security and or reduce the impact... In the worst case the vulnerability will trigger before/without those having any effect.

Comment: Can you give some examples of where more secure settings have resulted in less security? The one I'm thinking of is when people say to replace passwords with public key authentication, and then the Debian OpenSSL thing happened. If they used both password and public key authentication then presumably they would be protected against weaknesses in both password as well as public key authentication. Is there a scenario where two-factor auth would be worse than single-factor auth?

Comment: My suggestion was only that if the bug/vulnerability is critical enough you will exposed regardless of any other settings you have configured. Not that additional security measures themselves will detract.  - If, for example, a bug, that allows remote command execution is  discovered, which gets triggered by sending a malformed username string, than it doesn't matter that normally you only allow access to specific users and that those users need to use both a correct password, private key and MFA token. In such a case the bug will be triggered before those things even get evaluated.

Comment: Cryptographically authenticated port knocking (IP whitelisting based on successful authentication) can be very secure, but it also increases the attack surface (now you need to worry about your port knock server getting compromised).